# Convert float representing hours to integer hours and minutes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, time

I'm using the standard equation of **distance / speed = arrival time**. This works fine, but the answer is a float number and most people would find it awkward to convert something like 1.75 hrs to be 1 hr and 45 minutes.

I want to take that final float number result and extract the hour(s) separately from the minutes as integers.

Here is what I've tried:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

float spd=[speed.text floatValue];

float dist=[distKnots.text floatValue];

//this give me the answer as a float

float arr=(dist/bs);

//this is how I showed it as an answer

//Here I need to convert "arr" and extract the hours & minutes as whole integers

arrivalTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.02f", arr];

[speed resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And this is the conversion I tried to do -- and on paper it works, but in code it's full of errors:

```
int justHours = arr*60;

int justMinutes = (arr*60)-(justHours*60);

//then for the user friendly answer:

arrivalTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%n hours and %n minutes", justHours, justMinutes];
```

I'm new to Objective-C and hoping there is a way to get this to work or a better way altogether to resolve this.

Comment: You should accept an answer either yours or not

Answer (score 3):

Your `arr` variable is already measured in hours, so you shouldn't be scaling it, just rounding it down:

```
int justHours = (int)arr;
```

and then your minutes is sixty times the (integer) difference between the original and rounded hours (i.e. the fractional part).

```
int justMinutes = (int)((arr - justHours) * 60);
```

Comment: `int justHours = arr;` is *truncating* not rounding.

Comment: Thanks, I know I screwed up the hypothetical (up too late), and I've taken it out. the math I'm getting from the answers so far is right on, but the problem is converting the floats into integers without getting errors... am I doing that part correct? or what needs to be done if not?

Comment: I would expect warnings, but not errors.  If you're getting warnings about unexpected truncation, cast to `(int)` per my updated example, which should let the compiler know that you think you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, to all who replied... your answer set me on the right path: here is the code I ended up putting in and it works perfectly:

    int justHours = floor(arr);
    int justMinutes = (int)((arr - hrs) * 60);

The float has to use the round down Floor

Answer (score 0):

The `int justHours = arr/60;` seems to be incorrect, it should be `int justHours = arr;`.

Answer (score 0):

check the NSNumber numberFormater class. I believe you can wrap your float with time format and the return it to the user.